# Convert coordinates from readShapePoly in R to long-lat coordinates

Tags: shapefile, r, coordinate-system

I'm trying to find some centroids of a shapefile for Danish municipalities and afterwards find the driving time between them. I use `R`'s `readShapePoly` function from `maptools` combined with the `gCentroid`function from `rgeos`, and everything works. However, I get spatialpoints such as

```
SpatialPoints:
     x       y
1 571860.7 6225016
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: NA
```

Which is clearly not something I can use in Google to grab travel times. I'm looking for a way to convert these numbers to longitude-latitude, but have no idea how.

When I read the data using `readOGR` from the `rgdal` library I get the same coordinates but it tells me the following about what I assume is the projection (but the coordinates are the same)

```
Slot "proj4string":
CRS arguments:
+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs
```

Reproducible example:
I've put the data for the example here: 
https://github.com/sebastianbarfort/shapefiles

This should reproduce the problem:

```
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

map = readShapePoly("~/Downloads/shapefiles-master/kommuner1983.shp")
centroid = gCentroid(map)
centroid
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `spTransform` to transform the coordinates to WGS84:

```
library("rgdal")
library("rgeos")

map <- readOGR(".", "kommuner1983")
map_wgs84 <- spTransform(map, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
plot(map_wgs84, axes=TRUE)
```

[image: plot]

```
gCentroid(map_wgs84)
# SpatialPoints:
#       x     y
# 1 10.05 55.96
# Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84
# +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

`rgdal::readOGR` is capable to read the projection information automatically.
`maptools` functions neither read nor write projection information, leaving it up to you to manage these details manually.

Comment: This was just what I was looking for.

Comment: @sBarfort If the answer solves your question then you might want to accept it. That way others will know that it is the correct answer.

Comment: You do not have the same control as gCentroid, but SpatialPolygons hold the centroid in the object. You can retrieve them as a matrix using: coordinates(map_wgs84)